# Automator throws error on download, but download still completes?

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a workflow, that downloads files from an FTP to my computer, using transmit and automator.

The action in automator looks like this:

[image: Image of the action]

The information for this action is correct, and the files of the remote file path are downloaded to my computer.

However, a 1/3rd of the way through the download (~200 files), automator throws an error:

[image: Image of the error message]

The download still continues, but the error stops automator from doing the rest of the workflow.

So my question is:
**How can I solve this error, or at least make the workflow continue after the error is displayed?**

Comment: Automator doesn’t have any conditionals or error handling like that - how any particular action deals with errors would be up to the developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to have  **Automator** continue on with the workflow without timing out.  With **AppleScript**, If you wrap the download command within a `with timeout of 1000` command (*1000 is in seconds. Use whatever number you think will work*), the script will now wait for up to 1000 seconds for the download command to complete, instead of the default of 120 seconds, before timing out or moving on to its next command.

So instead of adding the **Automator Transmit Download** action to your **Automator Workflow**, you can insert a **Run AppleScript** command to your **Workflow**

---

For example let's say you want to download every currently selected file on the `remote browser of the current tab` in **Transmit.app** without timimg out, you would insert a **Run AppleScript** command to your **Workflow** and insert this following AppleScript code.  (obviously editing the properties in the code to suit your needs.)

```
property downloadLocation : POSIX path of (path to desktop)
property filesToDownload : missing value

tell application "Transmit"
    tell its document "Transmit"
        set selectedFiles to a reference to selected browser items of ¬
            (get remote browser of current tab)
        if (count of selectedFiles) > 0 then
            set filesToDownload to path of selectedFiles
        else
            return
        end if
        repeat with thisFile in filesToDownload
            with timeout of 1200 seconds
                download remote browser of current tab item at path thisFile to ¬
                    downloadLocation with resume mode resume
            end timeout
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

[image]

Comment: I would say this is a strictly better  solution to what I did. See my reply to mockman up above.

Comment: @eengstroem If you view my solution as  “a strictly better solution to what I did”, why not consider upvoting it and or select it as the accepted solution?

Comment: Yeah, I wish I could accept both. Mockman explained the error, while you provided a work-around. I still ended up letting the script run with the code I posted, in a separate workflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is from Panic's [library](https://library.panic.com/transmit/transmit5/synchronize/):

> When configuring Automator to Upload or Sync large files, Automator
> can experience an error: “The action “Synchronize” encountered an
> error: “The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1)”. We’ve
> also seen this error present as: -1712, -1753, and -1. -1 being the
> most common.
>
> Unfortunately, Apple has instituted a 2-minute timeout for Automator
> actions for macOS versions 10.14 and above. We’ve reported this to
> Apple, but at this time, there is not a fix or workaround.

If this sounds like the issue you're facing (you don't mention your version of OS or Transmit) then maybe you can adapt the workflow to process the list of files in chunks.

Comment: Yeah, this seems likely to cause the issue. Thanks @Mockman.

Comment: Hope you can find a way to route around it.

Comment: The error is caused by the timeout, from the link you provided. The download can complete, however, the warning stops further actions in the workflow. I worked around this, by having a separate workflow for the download only.